# Как изменить тип проекта в Visual Studio Community 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

При создании проекта выбрал пустой проект, т.к. не планировал использовать формы Windows. Сейчас же появилась необходимость в них. Добавлять форму через создание элемента нельзя - их попросту нет, только код. Можно ли изменить тип проекта? C++.

Comment: В `c++` нет никаких форм.

Comment: удаляете старый, ставите компонент mfc и вперед